# Update data with PHP ans MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP and I'm kinda stuck. I trying to figure out how to integrate the `Edit` option for the current data.

Currently, this is how it looks [like](https://prnt.sc/qra31y)

Here is the table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_return_amount` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `current_user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tax_return_amount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tax_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`current_user_id` is the ID of the registered user.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tax_amount_update']) && isset($_POST['tax_year_update'])) {

    $tax_update_amount = $_POST['tax_amount_update'];
    $tax_update_year = $_POST['tax_year_update'];

    // Get the current user id
    global $post;
    $order_id = $post->ID;
    $user_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', true);

    $update = "UPDATE wp_return_amount SET ";
    $update .= "tax_return_amount = '{$tax_update_amount}', ";
    $update .= "tax_year = '{$tax_update_year}' ";
    $update .= "WHERE current_user_id = '{$user_id}' ";


    if (!$conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
        echo "Error: " . $update . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

`$user_id` is the ID of the specific order inside the WooCommerce.

When I edit the data, it works, but its influences on everything and not only on the specific one. So, I guess that I need the relation between these.

So my question is what/how is the best way to create the relation so I can later change only the selected one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'influences on everything and not only on the specific one' ?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: "its influences on everything"...do you mean it updates all the rows and not just one? Have you tried to debug by seeing what SQL query is actually being executed?

Comment: @ADyson Yes. When I edit the data it updates all of the rows. Nope, how can I do that?

Comment: @RomiHalasz When I edit the data it updates every row, and not just one.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried to inspect the generated SQL query to see whether its `WHERE` condition match whatever it should?

Comment: @batman why don't you use the primary key to update row? this query will update all the records against the current user id

Comment: " how can I do that"...just `var_dump($update);` before the `if (!$conn->query...` line, so it will dump out the finalised query to the screen, and you can check it appears the way you expected. You can then even copy it and run it direct in MySQL to see how it behaves. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php - it's a basic debugging tool for looking at the value of variables during the execution of your code. It will normally output to the standard output but you can redirect it to a file instead, for general logging.)

Comment: P.S. are you sure it updates **all rows**, or just **all rows for the identified user**? Because it should be restricting by the user ID at least (unless that value is wrong). Maybe you need to be restricting by the order ID specifically? I don't know, because you didn't say specifically what the query is supposed to achieve. N.B. if you only have one user id in that table, that would explain why it appears to update all the rows - but then again that would be a very poor set of data to be testing with!

Comment: @ADyson It updates all data for the identified user. So what do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend putting the order ID in the WHERE clause instead of the user ID (assuming you want it to only update for the specific order - you didn't actually specify what you want it to do! - and assuming that the table contains the order ID). So actually maybe I first recommend that you tell us what precisely you want it to do instead of that, and then we can advise you properly.

Comment: @ADyson Ok. So [this](https://prnt.sc/qra31y) is all of the data from the specific `order_id` and from the specific user (current_user_id). So I have a relation between `order_id` and `current_user_id` but I don't have a relation between the Edit button and a specific row. 

So, when I click on Edit and edit the data, everything will be changed, but I need to change only that specific row. 

Hope I was clear now. If you need more info, I will provide it.

Comment: " I don't have a relation between the Edit button and a specific row"...that sounds like the thing you need to fix then.

Comment: @ADyson Can you advise me how?

Comment: No, because I don't know how you are constructing that HTML, or what it looks like when it's constructed, or where you got the data for it from. I can't read your disk, your screen...or your mind. If you want help with something, show it. I don't know what it is which uniquely identifies each row in that screenshot...is it the order ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$update = "UPDATE wp_return_amount SET ";
$update .= "tax_return_amount = '{$tax_update_amount}', ";
$update .= "tax_year = '{$tax_update_year}' ";
$update .= "WHERE current_user_id = '{$user_id}' ";
$update .= "AND id = '{$order_id}' ";
```

You need to get the exact id of the record if you want to change it. Currently you are updating all records that belong to current_user_id = '{$user_id}'. No relation needed.

::EDIT::
Due to @Nico Hasse complaint I would also advise you to change your query into:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($update);
$stmt->execute([
    'tax_update_amount' => $tax_update_amount
    'tax_update_year' => $tax_update_year,
    'current_user_id' => $current_user_id,
    'id' => $order_id
]);
```

and update fields in the query with corresponding params

```
    :tax_update_amount  
    :tax_update_year  
    :current_user_id  
    :id
```

instead of inputted $variables

Comment: Please don't recommend anything that still involves vulnerable code

Comment: Well it's up to him to start using PDO and prepared statements. I have just found the bug in his code.